# How to Login with Google?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, axios

I am trying to implement a google oauth 2.0 login without using any libraries in my Node.js application.

I have created an app on the Google API console with the redirect url as `http://localhost:3000`. During login my `response_type` is `code` which returns a one-time use code that needs to be exchanged with the token_endpoint as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#exchangecode). 
The exchange is done on my node.js server with the following snippet.

```js
axios({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      code: code,
      client_id: sso.clientId,
      client_secret: sso.clientSecret,
      redirect_uri: sso.redirect_uri,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.response.data);
  });
```

But this is is sending me back an error response of

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

instead of the user token.

Please help me identify the issue.

I tried doing a POSTMAN query as well with the same payload in the `raw` with content-type set to `application/json`, and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Can you confirm that other fields in your POST request like the `client_id , client_secret , redirect_uri` are correct?

Comment: Yes. The same creds are working when I login to get the `code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `params` in place of your `data` while making your exchange call through axios, revised block will be like

```
params: {
    code: code,
    client_id: sso.clientId,
    client_secret: sso.clientSecret,
    redirect_uri: sso.redirect_uri,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked !! Thanks a lot. The google docs said
'The request must include the following parameters in the POST body:', hence I was using the `data` ..

Answer (score -1):

NEVER include things like a clientSecret in GET parameters. This can lead to serious security issues !

The google doc is very clear about **how** to send the `data` ;

As a POST body - as always in [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) :
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer - Step 5, REST code sample

They must be sent as a string but in the POST body / `data` :

The string is the urlencoded parameters like

```
code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https://yourOauth2redirectUrl.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Comment: Is this a concern even when my code is running on the server and not in the browser ?

Comment: It depends on your server then. TLS (SSL) is the only security layer. Whenever something is wrong with SSL (e.g. you forgot to renew a certificate) you have a problem. There are 3 important things for OAuth Security: • Exactly follow the specification • Use TLS correctly • Use the state parameter - BTW : I wrote indieauth-node which will be published by the weekend here : https://github.com/redaktor/ - it also contains OAuth1 and OAuth2 modules (perfectly working with google) ... Feel free to ask further Qs here ...